# Why is Accountmanager.get(context).getAccounts() returning securityexception?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

It was my understanding that `Accountmanager.get(context).getAccounts` could not return a securityexception because it does not require permissions. From the documentation:

> Clients of this method that have not been granted the GET_ACCOUNTS
>   permission, will only see those accounts managed by
>   AbstractAccountAuthenticators whose signature matches the client.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccounts()

So it reads as though if you haven't got `GET_ACCOUNTS` then that's fine, but my app is crashing when calling the method with the following exception:

> caller uid # lacks any of android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS

Why would this happen?

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(parentActivity).getAccounts();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app lacks of the matching permission in your manifest.
Add

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml

Edit: For Android 6.0, request it at runtime: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

> GET ACCOUNTS:
>   Allows access to the list of accounts in the Accounts Service.
>   Protection level: dangerous

Comment: I removed GET_ACCOUNTS from the manifest in this version of the app because it wasn't supposed to be used anymore. Does the AccountManager require it as a mandatory addition to the manifest? It might be worth pointing out that I can't reproduce this issue on my own phone - everything works fine despite not having GET_ACCOUNTS in the manifest. I only have a user who keeps crashing like this.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS - it is a dangerous permission and needs to be requested.

Comment: The question is whether just adding the permission to the manifest is enough or whether I would have to actually request it under android M. The documentation of accountmanager made me think that I didn't have to

Comment: You ideally do both: request in manifest to support devices < MarchMallow, and request at runtime to use the Android 6 permission system.

Comment: but if I didnt request it - it wouldn't crash under android m, is that correct? The documentation seems to say that if the user doesn't have the permission it will default to some other behavior that doesn't cause a crash